# Swing looks zoomed after upgrading java

Tags: java, swing, java-8, java-11, java-13

I have a old application running a Swing client. I upgraded from Java 7 to 8 a long time ago. The upgrade went fine. Ever since I have wanted to upgrade to Java 9, then 11 and now 13. However this is where I meet problems.

The UI looks fine and as intended with Java 8, but any newer Java version will somehow change the font sizes and maybe components for some reason. I do not have any pictures to show because the application is maintained on a network without internet access because of security reasons. The client looks like most thing is multiplied with a factor of 2.0 or something. It appears as zoomed or maybe something you would create with universal design in mind. Even the splash screen is doubled in size for some reason and that is an image. There are some exeptions. The title text in the windows is the same. Also text on buttons and lables seems to be equal. Icons, images (splash) and text inside textfields/editors is much larger.

I have tried to find a solution for a long time but have not found anything. I am hoping someone else have experienced this problem or at least know what the problem could be.

Comment: *"I am hoping someone else have experienced this problem or at least know what the problem could be."* It's likely the code you have not shared. Post a [mre] that reproduces the problem.

Comment: That’s the scaling factor you (resp. the user) has configured in the display settings of your operating system. The good news is that Java is not ignoring that setting anymore.

Comment: I am not allowed to share the source in any way. I have however tried to reproduce the problem myself earlier by creating a swing client and running it on both java 8 and 11. The problem did not occur. This is no small application and it is impossible to give a minimal example. I was hoping there was some Swing gurus out there that could tell me what it might be. I have asked several colleges at work with more Swing experience than me but no luck. I have also asked a former colleage that have Swing Black belt but no luck.

Comment: Swing is NOT backwards compatible between Java 8→Java 9.

Comment: As said, there is a scaling factor in the display settings of your operating system. If you keep it at 100%, you won’t reproduce the “problem”. Newer devices, with very high DPI numbers usually have settings with a scaling factor. Most applications respect this. Java, up to version 8 did ignore this, which made its appearance (esp. fonts which were the same as for other applications) smaller than usual. Which didn’t matter, as long as the scaling factor did not differ much. Today, this is unacceptable, so the factor is respected by Java as well.

Comment: Holger you saved my day! Thank you. I can confirm this solved the problem. I have a 4K screen and had scaled to 150%. Going back to 100% made the Swing client go back to normal values aswell. I do need to have scaling av 150% so now I must figure out how to override the scaling in Java at least for development purposes.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Holgers comment about OS scaling was the issue. I have a 4K screen with 150% scaling set in the OS. Putting it back to 100% made the Java Swing Client look the same as when running Java 8.

To override add `-Dsun.java2d.uiScale=1`

Se also https://superuser.com/questions/988379/how-do-i-run-java-apps-upscaled-on-a-high-dpi-display