# Java Swing graphics resolution and dimensions distorted in JDK10

Tags: java, swing, java-8, java-10

I've updated the compiler version for a basic Swing project from JDK1.8 to JDK10. This has resulted in poorer image resolution, and sizes/dimensions of JPanels now appear different. See screenshots for J8 vs J10:

Java 8:
[image: Java 8:]

Java 10:
[image: Java 10:]

Below is the entire app code:

```
package com.nickjwhite.test;

import java.awt.Color;
import java.awt.Dimension;
import java.awt.GridBagConstraints;
import java.awt.GridBagLayout;
import java.awt.Image;
import java.awt.Insets;
import java.awt.image.BufferedImage;
import java.io.IOException;

import javax.imageio.ImageIO;
import javax.swing.ImageIcon;
import javax.swing.JFrame;
import javax.swing.JLabel;
import javax.swing.JPanel;
import javax.swing.JScrollPane;


public class App {

    //UI objects
    private JFrame frame;
    private JPanel contentPane;


    /**
     * Launch the application.
     */
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        new App();
    }

    public App() {
        try {

            //
            //
            //Initialise Parent Frame
            //
            //
            setFrame(new JFrame());
            getFrame().setSize(1200,800); // Dimensions of non-Maximised frame
            getFrame().setTitle("Test App");
            getFrame().setLocationRelativeTo(null); // Centre the frame
            getFrame().setExtendedState(JFrame.MAXIMIZED_BOTH); // Maximise the frame on launch
            getFrame().setIconImage(ImageIO.read(getClass().getClassLoader().getResourceAsStream("test.jpg")));
            getFrame().setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE); // Kill process if window closed
            getFrame().setVisible(true);


            //
            //
            //Main content panel
            //
            //
            contentPane = new JPanel(new GridBagLayout());
            contentPane.setBackground(Color.decode("#2e3131"));
            getFrame().setContentPane(contentPane);


            //
            //
            //MenuPanel
            //
            //
            JPanel menuPanel = new JPanel();

                //Initialise Menu

                // Title Background
                //
                JPanel menuTitleBg = new JPanel();
                menuTitleBg.setLayout(new GridBagLayout());
                menuTitleBg.setBackground(Color.decode("#d5b8ff"));

                GridBagConstraints menuTitleBg_constraints = new GridBagConstraints();
                menuTitleBg_constraints.fill = GridBagConstraints.BOTH;
                menuTitleBg_constraints.gridx = 0;
                menuTitleBg_constraints.gridy = 0;
                menuTitleBg_constraints.weightx = 1;
                menuTitleBg_constraints.weighty = 0;
                menuPanel.add(menuTitleBg, menuTitleBg_constraints);

                JLabel testImage = new JLabel();

                GridBagConstraints testImage_constraints = new GridBagConstraints();
                testImage_constraints.insets = new Insets(10, 10, 10, 10);
                testImage_constraints.gridx = 0;
                testImage_constraints.gridy = 0;

                testImage.setSize(new Dimension(80,80));
                testImage.setOpaque(false);
                menuTitleBg.add(testImage,testImage_constraints);

                try {
                    BufferedImage img = ImageIO.read(App.class.getClassLoader().getResourceAsStream("test.jpg"));
                    Image dimg = img.getScaledInstance(testImage.getWidth(), testImage.getHeight(), Image.SCALE_SMOOTH);

                    testImage.setIcon(new ImageIcon(dimg));
                } catch (IOException e) {
                    e.printStackTrace();
                }





            menuPanel.setLayout(new GridBagLayout());
            menuPanel.setBackground(Color.decode("#9b59b6"));
            menuPanel.setPreferredSize(new Dimension(400, (int) (contentPane.getPreferredSize().height)));
            menuPanel.setMinimumSize(new Dimension(400,10));
            GridBagConstraints gbc_panel = new GridBagConstraints();
            gbc_panel.fill = GridBagConstraints.BOTH;
            gbc_panel.gridx = 0;
            gbc_panel.gridy = 0;
            gbc_panel.weightx = 0;
            gbc_panel.weighty = 1;

            JScrollPane menuScrollPane = new JScrollPane(menuPanel);
            menuScrollPane.setHorizontalScrollBarPolicy(JScrollPane.HORIZONTAL_SCROLLBAR_NEVER);
            menuScrollPane.setVerticalScrollBarPolicy(JScrollPane.VERTICAL_SCROLLBAR_AS_NEEDED);
            menuScrollPane.setPreferredSize(new Dimension(400, (int) (contentPane.getPreferredSize().height)));

            contentPane.add(menuScrollPane , gbc_panel);


            //
            //
            //Action Window Panel
            //
            //
            JPanel actionWindow = new JPanel();
            actionWindow.setLayout(new GridBagLayout());
            actionWindow.setBackground(Color.decode("#2e3131"));
            GridBagConstraints gbc_actionWindow = new GridBagConstraints();
            gbc_actionWindow.anchor = GridBagConstraints.EAST;
            gbc_actionWindow.fill = GridBagConstraints.BOTH;
            gbc_actionWindow.gridx = 1;
            gbc_actionWindow.gridy = 0;
            gbc_actionWindow.weightx = 1;
            gbc_actionWindow.weighty = 1;

            contentPane.add(actionWindow, gbc_actionWindow);
        } catch (IOException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }

    public JFrame getFrame() {
        return frame;
    }

    public void setFrame(JFrame frame) {
        this.frame = frame;
    }

}
```

I need to continue compiling with JDK10 for this project, but need the GUI to reflect the JDK8 output, preferably acheiving this without having to adjust the menuPanel Preferred Size, or the testImage dimenstions.

Anyone know what's caused this?

[image: test.jpg]

Comment: Please provide a [mre] that demonstrates the problem.  And I have been doing `graphics` even prior to Swing and I have not seen any difference in the resolution between versions.

Comment: I just ran my own test (I didn't have your images) using Java 8 and Java 10.  I observed no difference in image resolution.  And the reported resolution parameters and DPI were also the same as well as other internal graphics  environment specifics.  Perhaps someone else can provide additional information.

Comment: This is odd. I had figured that my Eclipse setup may have been responsible, but I'm seeing the same results if I compile with javac / maven outside of the IDE. I also get the same results using JDK9 as I do with JDK10 (Required changes included in v9 were the reason for the version upgrade). I haven't tried any higher versions as these don't seem to be supported by Photon.

Comment: If you attach your images I will try them.

Comment: "test.jpg" (chrome logo) as used in the code above attached. Thanks

Comment: Just a suggestion. Instead of `ImageIO`, try [new ImageIcon(URL)](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/javax/swing/ImageIcon.html#ImageIcon-java.net.URL-)

Comment: How should the URL be constructed from the Image resource?

Comment: Refer to _javadoc_. Method [getClass(String)](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/lang/Class.html#getResource-java.lang.String-) in class `java.lang.Class`.

Comment: I am unable to get the same results as you. Are you certain the posted code displayed the shown images?  And what PC/OS are you using?

Comment: You are scaling the image to the size of `testImage`, but despite your calling testImage.setSize, the size of testImage is actually determined by the layout of its parent, which in this case is the GridBagLayout of `menuTitleBg`.  In other words, you are resizing your image to something that is not reliable or consistent.  If you want your image to be 80×80 pixels, just pass 80 to `getScaledInstance`.

Comment: I'm on Windows 10. What I've now noticed is that the displays are identical if I attach a monitor with 1280 x 1024 res, but I still see the crappy graphics with J10 on my main screen which is set to 1920 x 1080 res.

Comment: Another symptom of [this issue](https://stackoverflow.com/q/58833100/2711488)?

Comment: Yes, that seems to be it. There was a 125% custom scaling by default on my primary laptop screen. Setting it back to 100% and both versions looked the same, as they do on my other screens (although a lot of other applications then look strange without the scaling). Is there a way to tell J10 to overrule the OS scaling?

Comment: If I reduce all my dimensions by 1.25, the layout sizes now appear correct vs the original with no scaling, but the affect of reducing image and font dimensions and then having the OS scale them up again has messed up the resolutions big time